# Is there a way to deploy backend (Kotlin) server application to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have already written a **backend server application**, which executes rather complicated tasks in Kotlin and it is running fine on my local machine.

I looked into Firebase and found out that you could host your website and create your database. My **server application** is basically a **database**, plus everything to handle it. I think that it should be possible to write the same database with **Firebase's database** too, but I think that that would require quite some time and I would need to learn how to access the database from **Android** and also *understand how the Firebase database works and how to implement my functionality*.

#### Concluding

My question basically is, *if it is possible to deploy my already written app to Firebase* and access it like before. Maybe through the website hosting and a link to my *Kotlin app*. I could not really find any information on how to do something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; No, this is not possible with Firebase, however there are alternatives.

Firebase is a Backend as a Service, this means, that they basically provide most functionality for you. The Database can be directly accessed from the client application (an android app for example), or a third party server. The website hosting is static, meaning you can't perform server side code, and instead only serve your pre-built Html/Css/Javascript.

They have recently introduced [Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which are basically small functions executed on their servers, which could fulfill your purpose, however those are currently only available in javascript, and probably have a vastly different architecture from your existing backend, due to their nature of being small functions.

If you don't want to rewrite everything to work with Firebase, I'd recommend going with a service like Heroku, which is a Platform as a Service. This means that you can [deploy your existing Kotlin backend to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-kotlin#introduction), and use that as the backend for your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already took a look at Heroku once, but didn't quite get it. Now I looked into it again and have problems with it again. I don't understand how I can push my existing IntelliJ project to Heroku. I got my `.jar` file running on Heroku, but it is not working (running on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 and crashing after 90 seconds). Do you know a source explaining how to do it in detail?

Comment: Have a look at their tutorial on getting started with Kotlin on Heroku, here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-kotlin#introduction    As long as your project is built with gradle, it should work with only minimal to no changes.

Comment: I found out that they only support HTTP connections, so I guess that it is the same effort to rewrite my own server as setting up firebase.

Comment: Even for making backend development with kotlin simple check this post https://medium.com/@mrcurious/a-complete-backend-only-with-kotlin-and-your-favourite-text-editor-582b4528688